# Display "'" symbol

Tags: sql, sql-server

My request is to display with "'" symbol in sql Server when I execute the text "select asdf'asdf'ddd" with F5 button, how shall I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double it.

```
"select asdf''asdf''ddd"
```

Though I expect this to fail, as `asdf'asdf'ddd` is probably *not* a table or other database object name.

If you want to select a string value, you need to enclose it in `'`:

```
select 'asdf''asdf''ddd'
```

Answer (score 1):

What you've asked doesn't make any sense.

If there is more to this SQL Statement, and `asdf'asdf'ddd` is a column name, you can enclose it in square brackets or double quotes:

```
SELECT [asdf'asdf'ddd]
FROM ...
```

If you're just looking to select that string to the console, you need to both double up all existing single quotes (as that symbol is used to denote a string).

You'll also need to enclose the string itself in these double quotes, which at the time of posting, neither of the other answers do (they will both produce syntax errors when run).

To print the example string to the console as is, you'll need this:

```
SELECT 'asdf''asdf''ddd'
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to escape that, escape character is `'`

```
select 'asdf''asdf''ddd'
```

Comment: This will produce a syntax error, you need to enclose the whole thing in single quotes too `select 'asdf''asdf''ddd'`

Comment: @Bridge: Thanks man for correcting, it skipped from my mind :)